# What parameters HasField function of protobuf expects?

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

Consider following structure

```
message Fly {
  uint32 dtime = 1;
}
```

But `HasField` function doesnt work:

```
>>> d.ListFields()[0][0].name
'dtime'
>>> d.ListFields()[0][0].full_name
'Fly.dtime'
>>> 
>>> d.HasField('dtime')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 825, in HasField
    raise ValueError(error_msg % field_name)
ValueError: Protocol message has no non-repeated submessage field "dtime"
>>> d.HasField('Fly.dtime')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/.../lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 825, in HasField
    raise ValueError(error_msg % field_name)
ValueError: Protocol message has no non-repeated submessage field "Fly.dtime"
```

What parameters does `HasField` expects?

Answer (score 10):

I think you've misunderstood what `HasField()` does. It does not check whether a protobuf type defines a specific field by a name. What it does is to check if, given the name of a *message* field, that that field is set for the current instance.

As the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/python-generated#singular-fields-proto3) notes, calling HasField for a non-message field in proto3 will raise an error.

Comment: So if `dtime` was a message type it would work? I am trying to get a list of  fields that were set (because protobuf set default values for primitive types), I can achieve that by iterating over ListFields but I was looking for nice solution.

Comment: @rkuska: Proto3 removed the concept of set vs. not-set for primitive fields. Your code would have worked with proto2, but not in proto3. What you can perhaps do is compare the field against its default value.

Comment: @KentonVarda is not the same as sometimes value set might be same as default value, I was looking for a solution which would show which optional parameters weren't set. Even `ListFields` won't work as it ignore those parameters which have default values set.

Comment: @rkuska: Right. Under proto3, there is no such thing as set/not set for integers. There is only default/not default. If you need that, you'll need to go back to proto2. At least, that's my understanding.